# Adding a second object to join model from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inner-join, rails-activerecord

I have a many to many relationship between `User` and `Company` which are joined by the model `UserCompany`.  When I build a new user, I also build a company, using my `users_controller`, which is as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user=User.new
        @company=@user.user_companies.build.build_company
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            # @user.companies << @company
            redirect_to users_admin_path(@user), notice: "User successfuly created!"
        else
            redirect_to welcome_index_path
        end
    end

end
```

This code above builds and saves a new user and a new company owned by that user, thereby creating a new entry in the user_companies database.

**The Problem:** I would like to know how to add a second entry, for a second, already existing user (call him @user2) to this join model. So I'm looking to create a new object `@user2.user_companies` and set its attributes (:user_id, :company_id, and :company_role) within the controller. Maybe something like this:

```
UserCompany.new(company_id: @company.id, user_id: "2", company_role:"owner")
```

How might this be accomplished?

Comment: Maybe you're a little confused about what M2M join tables (and models) do? The `user_companies` table works as link between a single User and Company. So no two users will have the same UserCompany.

Comment: If you want to link `@user2` to the same company as `@user` its a different row in the `user_companies` table.

Comment: You can hack it and add another relation to `UserCompany` but that is most likely not what you really want.

Comment: @max YES! that's it! (the second comment) how do I create a second row in the join table for an already existing user when I create a new user?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense.  If you do `@user = User.create; @user2 = User.create` it will insert two different rows in the `users` table. If you do `@user.companies << @company; @user2.companies << @company` you'll see that it will insert two different rows into `user_companies` both which point to the same company_id but different user_id.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to get to is that there is no difference in creating the association on `@user2`. However how you string it together in your controller and form really depends on what you want the user to be able to do. To me it just sounds like something which may be better split in several actions rather than having a mega signup form where the user creates a profile and a company and assigns a bunch of employees at once. Split it up and use ajax to improve the user experience to make it more fluid if needed.

Comment: @max that's a fair concern, so let me give you a little more context as to why I'm doing this.  In the app, a user is created by an administrator.  When that user and the respective company are created I want the administrator who created the user to be linked to that new user's new company as well.  That's all.  So basically I'm trying to create two entries in the join: one for the new user and one for the `current_user`.  I'm very sorry this has been so convoluted; I don't mean to make your head spin.

Comment: No problem. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the first user is pretty straight forward:

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@company = Company.new(name: 'Acme')
UserCompany.create(user: @user, company: @company, company_role: "owner")
```

If you want the `current_user` to be associated with `@company` as well you simply need to create another `UserCompany`:

```
UserCompany.create(
   user: current_user, 
   company: @company, 
   company_role: "some other role"
)
```

Then if you query `@company.users` you will get:

```
id | name
1  | admin
2  | new user
```

When you query `@company.user_companies` you will get:

```
id | user_id | company_id | company_role
1  | 2       | 1          | "owner"
2  | 1       | 1          | "some other role"
```

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for the response.  I think my question might not have been clear.  The @user is creating an entry in the join model with no problem.  My goal is to create a SECOND join model entry for another particular, already existing user (call him @user2).  How might I do that?

Comment: I reread my question and it was definitely not clear.  I've updated it above to reflect what I'm describing in my comment.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass attributes to the `build` method, and they'll automatically be set on the new record being built:

Let's say you have an existing company, `@company` and you'd like to add `@user` to the company in the owner role:

```
user_company = @user.user_companies.build(company: @company, company_role: "owner")
```

If company `has_many :user_companies`, you could also do this the other way around, starting with the company:

```
user_company = @company.user_companies.build(user: @user, company_role: "owner")
```

You can find more detailed information about associations and building records in the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference).

Comment: thanks for the response.  I tried both above but neither "worked."  In checking the development logs and there aren't any errors although the attributes from the controller don't seem to be making it to the parameters.  Maybe there's some confusion regarding my question? To be clear, the issue isn't that I can't get any user_companies to save.  It's that I'm trying to figure out how to manually insert a second one.  Also, the associations are as you described.

Comment: I re-read my question above and it wasn't very clear.  I've revised it to better describe the issue.  Sorry for the confusion.